# Get the query generated by LINQ toward EF Core SqLite In Memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core

I am using EF core SQLite In memory for unit testing.
I want to see the query is generated by LINQ like SQL Profiler so that I could optimize the query.
Is there any way to check the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this link for full explanation: [Logging - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3)

If you want to log to console: Install package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

`dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`

Then create a logger factory implementation:

```
public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
    = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); });
```

Then, in your DbContext onConfiguring overrid method, add the .UseLoggerFactory call:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
    .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
    .UseSqlServer(
        @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFLogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
```

Comment: Now I am able to see the query. But the parameters values are not available. Is it possible to see them?

Answer (score 0):

Two options

```
dotnet ef migrations script

dotnet ef migrations script 20190725054716_Add_new_tables 20190829031257_Add_another_table
```

You can pipe the output to a file if you want. Beyond this you need to also post the Unit test functions.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, click on View/SQL Server Object Explorer and check your Tables if its populating. If not, then you have to add scaffolding.

Right click on the Project/Add/New Scaffold/MVC Controller with views, using EF.

Check this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: This doesn't work with SQLite. I can see my local SQL Server, but not the SQLite Db in the project or solution.